# Splitting a string with a space/two spaces after the character

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, string, split

Consider a number of strings, which are assumed to contain "keys" of the form "Wxxx", where x are digits from 0-9. Each one can contain either one only, or multiple ones, separated by ',' followed by two spaces. For example:

```
W123
W432
W546,  W234,  W167
```

The ones that contain multiple "keys" need to be split up, into an array. So, the last one in the above examples should be split into an array like this: `{"W546", "W234", "W167"}`.

As a quick solution, `String.Split` comes to mind, but as far as I am aware, it can take one character, like ','. The problem is that it would return an array with like this: `{"W546", "  W234", "  W167"}`. The two spaces in all the array entries from the second one onwards can probably be removed using `Substring`, but is there a better solution?

For context, these values are being held in a spreadsheet, and are assumed to have undergone data validation to ensure the "keys" are separated by a comma followed by two spaces.

```
while ((ws.Cells[row,1].Value!=null) && (ws.Cells[row,1].Value.ToString().Equals("")))
{
    // there can be one key, or multiple keys separated by ','
    if (ws.Cells[row,keysCol].Value.ToString().Contains(','))
    {
        // there are multiple
        // need to split the ones in this cell separated by a comma           
    }
    else
    {
        // there is one
    }

    row++;
}
```

Comment: Split can take a string array as param. Wouldn’t that solve your issue. You can split on multiple variations of comma/space as well if your data isn’t completely fixed format

Comment: Always check the formatting of your question.  The fact that the first two values are on separate lines got lost in the formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an old favorite--Regular Expressions.

Here are two flavors 'Loop' or 'LINQ'.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list = new List<string>{"W848","W998, W748","W953, W9484, W7373","W888"};

        Console.WriteLine("LINQ");
        list.ForEach(l => TestSplitRegexLinq(l));

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Loop");
        list.ForEach(l => TestSplitRegexLoop(l));
    }


    private static void TestSplitRegexLinq(string s)
    {
        string pattern = @"[W][0-9]*";                
        var reg = new Regex(pattern);
        reg.Matches(s).ToList().ForEach(m => Console.WriteLine(m.Value));
    }



    private static void TestSplitRegexLoop(string s)
    {
        string pattern = @"[W][0-9]*";                
        var reg = new Regex(pattern);
        foreach (Match m in reg.Matches(s))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
        }
    }
```

Just replace the `Console.Write` with anything you want: eg. `myList.Add(m.Value)`.

You will need to add the NameSpace: `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;`

Comment: [... now you have two problems](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/) ... just sayin'.

Comment: @Filburt : Thanks for that link. I truly enjoyed the read. Not certain about your intentions, but my take away:
“I love regex.” - love may be too strong, but ok.
“Regular expressions rock. They should absolutely be a key part of every modern coder's toolkit.” - Maybe not “key part”, but every developer should be aware of the strengths and weaknesses.
“..regex are incredibly powerful and succinct.” - sometimes, yes. In my answer above, absolutely.
“If you're afraid of regular expressions, don't be. Start small.” - it doesn’t get any simpler or smaller than: [W][0-9]* :: sage ich nur

Comment: One of the gems of Coding Horror for sure. Just felt your answer needed this grain of salt to go with my +1.

Answer (score 4):

You can just specify `','` and `' '` as separators and `RemoveEmptyEntries`.

Using your sample of single keys and a string containing multiple keys you can just handle them all the same and get your list of individual keys:

```
List<string> cells = new List<string>() { "W123", "W432", "W546,  W234,  W167" };
List<string> keys = new List<string>();

foreach (string cell in cells)
{
    keys.AddRange(cell.Split(new char[] { ',', ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
}
```

`Split` can handle strings where's nothing to split and `AddRange` will accept your single keys as well as the multi-key split results.

Comment: FYI those first two values are actually on separate lines.  The formatting of the question caused them to all appear as one line.

Comment: Now it looks like it's not separate lines, but just 3 examples of what the data looks like, so the splitting it only needed for the 3 values separated by a comma and two spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Eliminate the extra space first (using `Replace()`), *then* use split.

```
var input = "W546, W234, W167";
var normalized = input.Replace(", ",",");  
var array = normalized.Split(',');
```

This way, you treat a comma followed by a space exactly the same as you'd treat a comma. If there might be two spaces you can also replace that:

```
var input = "W546,  W234, W167";
var normalized = input.Replace("  "," ").Replace(", ",",");  
var array = normalized.Split(',');
```

Comment: So the question was not formatted properly.  Those first two values are actually on separate lines.

Comment: I see. I adjusted my answer.

Comment: They are in separate Excel cells in reality. The Epplus library is being used to check the value of the cells one by one, and if there are multiple, then the attempt is being made to split them. I will add some code to the original post to illustrate this.

Answer (score 0):

After trying this in .NET fiddle, I think I may have a solution:

```
// if there are multiple
string keys = ws.Cells[row,keysCol].Value.ToString();

// remove spaces
string keys_normalised = keys.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
Console.WriteLine("Checking that spaces have been removed: " + keys3_normalised + "\n");

string[] splits = keys3_normalised.Split(',');
for (int i = 0; i < splits.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(splits[i]);
}
```

This produces the following output in the console:

```
Checking that spaces have been removed: W456,W234,W167

W456
W234
W167
```